# Where are the alleged advertisements?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I find people asserting that Stack Exchange is paid for by advertising revenue.  In the course of almost four years of posting on Stack Exchange almost daily and amassing a reputation of more than 100,000, I don't recall ever seeing anything that looked like a paid advertisement.  I don't fail to notice them on Facebook and Google.  Is it really subtle subliminal stuff?  Where is it found?

Comment: Adblock? that 120rep  privilege?

Comment: Your questions might be better received if you're a little less confrontational about them. This one comes off like you think that since you have so much reputation (humblebrag), you think it's probably everyone else who's wrong.

Comment: @Jefromi : I don't think it would have occurred to me to think that I think everyone else is wrong.  The point about reputation is that if I've been here for a long time, I would expect to see something if it's here.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I didn't say you meant it that way, I said it comes off that way. If you don't mean it to sound like that, all the more reason to try to avoid it.

Answer (score 6):

Like me you have not signed up for [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions) and so I think when you follow the preceding link to its questions you will see an advertisement on the right hand side.

Click refresh a few times to see that advertisement change.  It seems to have paid and free ads intermixed.

[image]

Comment: I see that advert on StackOverflow too and am well over the "no advert" limit. The adverts I don't see are the ones intermingled with answers.